# How shrink and center a container while keeping it's contents left-aligned?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a page layout and would appreciate some help. Here's what I'm wanting:

[image]

If the browser's width is decreased, then the 3rd grey div should drop down (forcing the last one to drop down as well), resulting in this:

[image]

So the green container should display as many as the grey inner containers as it can, while shrinking it's width and keeping itself centered.

My current code close to what I'm wanting, as the grey divs drop down when the page is resized, but the problem is that the grey divs are centered (putting them out of alignment with each other in the bottom row), making the output looks like this:

[image]

While I'm wanting it to look like this:

[image]

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2S7gz/5/

How can this be accomplished?

Current HTML:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="outerContainer">
        <div class="innerContainer">
            inner container
        </div>

        <div class="innerContainer">
            inner container
        </div>

        <div class="innerContainer">
            inner container
        </div>    

        <div class="innerContainer">
            inner container
        </div>   

        <div class="innerContainer">
            inner container
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.body {
    background-color: #fee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
}

.outerContainer {
    background-color: #efe;
    display: inline-block;
}

.innerContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the green div an approximate width value? I would not suggest making a class "body" that is going to goof something up :(

Comment: Are the inner containers always going to be of equal width?

Comment: Will this work out? http://jsfiddle.net/GcH93/2/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I just added the body div so that I could change the background color, to make it clear that I wanted the green container to be shrunk & centered

Comment: @monners Yes, the inner containers will always be the same width.

Comment: Ahhhh ok :) Well then that is totally fine!

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Thanks for your help, but your JSFiddle has the outer container being fixed width, and I want it to be fluid.

Comment: You might need a fixed width in order to do only three elements on the first line. I could 100% be wrong though.

Comment: Are you inclined to use JQuery, because I don't think you can do this with just CSS?

Comment: **center** something while keeping it **left aligned** ????

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi I updated my question to make what I'm trying to achieve clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I shifted a few things around. Is this okay? Basically, I changed the container `div` to a `span` element, and gave it a fixed width. (You mentioned the boxes will always be the same width)

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2S7gz/2/).

**EDIT**: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2S7gz/4/) I've done a few extra things.

You cannot margin:auto to center the div that has `max-width` and `display:inline-block` set, BUT you can use `text-align:center` - which is recognized by all major browsers. By doing this, we are centering the div while keeping the integrity of the fluidity of it. We're also avoiding the use of tables. If the browser size is made too small, the smaller divs will 'jump' down and your container will resize.  To avoid centering all of your text, we've added `text-align:left` to `outerContainer`.

Basically, the answer here is `text-align:center` and `max-width`. That combination is the gold you're after.

Comment: no this is not what he wants. It has to be fluid. If the screen gets smaller the gray blocks needs to float down

Comment: @smts Your updated Fiddle is closer, but they green outer container needs to be centered (while keeping the grey inner containers left-aligned inside it). That's where I'm stuck at.

Comment: @smts I updated my question to give a better explanation of what I'm after. Your last try is sort of close, but try making the width of the viewing pane slightly smaller so that the grey containers drop down and you'll see that they aren't centered any more (compare what happens to the image I posted of what I'm trying to get).

Comment: @Nate I've been literally trying this all night. I so wish I had a better answer for you. If someone else has one, I hope they post it here. I'm afraid the above is the best I can do with CSS. I can probably rig something up with JavaScript if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

This is... a hard problem specifically because the only way to constantly recenter the inner contents of a div after numerous resizes is probably going to entail a JQuery or JavaScript solution. However, if you are just looking to be able to resize the width while have the contents stay somewhat aligned as they should, then this may be the solution.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GcH93/3/)

Let's take a look at the CSS used:

```
.outerContainer {
    /* max-width: 100%; */ /* This can also be used */
    width: auto; /*creates that fluidity */
    margin: 25px;
    background-color: #efe;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Looking at my comments above, we notice that the width is auto. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) states that auto means `'The browser will calculate and select a width for the specified element.'`. This is helpful because it will allow for the notion that you no longer need a fixed width.

I also did a little centering using `display: table-cell;` which allows for the div to act as a type of td, which, when partnered with `vertical-align:middle;` it will center everything in the box accordingly. This is found in your outermost div that you have conveniently named "body".

I can also tell you that there is probably a JavaScript solution that will be able to recenter everything as the div grows or shrinks (without zooming in or out or vice versa) and this works because JavaScript is a browser or client-side scripting language, meaning that it will allow for the browser to update without sending a signal back to the server and refreshing the page (as opposed to other languages such as Perl, Ruby, or Php).

With that being said, you may need to find a JavaScript solution to recenter everything in the div(if that is your main goal) but with pure CSS, this is as good as it will get without fixing the positions of all of the inner divs.

My last note is that positioning is relatively... dangerous due to the fact that it can continuously keep moving after the window zooms in and out. If you want things to stay absolutely still or somewhat close to that, I would advise using a float variable to keep things or ensure things are in place and using another definition of MDN, which states that all left floats `must float on the left side of its containing block` and all right floats `must float on the right side of its containing block`.